# Loop diagrams with derivative couplings

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, regularization

Consider the following Lagrangian of two massless scalars in 3+1D interacting through derivative interaction:
$$
{\scr L} = \frac12(\partial a)^2(1 + g b) + \frac12(\partial b)^2,
$$
where $g$ is a coupling constant with mass dimension $-1$. The interaction in this theory is described by the vertex factor
$$
-igp_{a,1}\cdot p_{a,2}
$$
where $p_{a,1}$ and $p_{a,2}$ are the $4-$momentum of the two $a$ particles directed into the vertex. I'm now interested in computing the two-loop vacuum bubble diagram in this theory utilizing a hard euclidean cutoff $\Lambda$. As there is only a cubic interaction, there is exactly one diagram at this order:

[image: vacuum bubble diagram]

I can compute this diagram by specifying $p_{1}$ running clockwise around the upper arc of the circle, $p_{2}$ running counter clockwise around the lower arc, and $p_{1}+p_{2}$ running from right to left along the middle. The diagram therefore evaluates to
$$
D = \frac{1}{4}\int\frac{d^4 p_{1}d^4 p_{2}}{(2\pi)^8}(- i g p_{1}\cdot p_{2})^2\frac{i}{p_{1}^2}\frac{i}{p_{2}^2}\frac{i}{(p_{1}+p_{2})^2}.
$$
Note that the factor of $1/4$ comes from the symmetry factor of the diagram.
Wick rotating and integrating up to $\Lambda$, we find
$$
D = \frac{i^2}{4}\int^\Lambda \frac{2\pi^2 p_{1}^3 4\pi \sin^2\theta p_{2}^3d p_{1} dp_{2}}{(2\pi)^8}(i g p_{1} p_{2}\cos\theta)^2\frac{-i}{p_{1}^2}\frac{-i}{p_{2}^2}\frac{-i}{(p_{1}^2 + p_{2}^2 + p_{1}p_{2}\cos\theta)} = \frac{5 i g^2 \Lambda ^6}{36864 \pi ^4}.
$$
However, I could have evaluated the diagram with the $a$-fields having any two of the momenta $p_{1}$, $p_{2}$ and $p_1 + p_2$. Writing out the diagram with these other momentum assignments, I find for both cases
$$
D = \frac{i^2}{4}\int^\Lambda \frac{2\pi^2 p_{1}^3 4\pi \sin^2\theta p_{2}^3d p_{1} dp_{2}}{(2\pi)^8}(i g (p_1^2 + p_{1} p_{2}\cos\theta))^2\frac{-i}{p_{1}^2}\frac{-i}{p_{2}^2}\frac{-i}{(p_{1}^2 + p_{2}^2 + p_{1}p_{2}\cos\theta)} = \frac{11 i g^2 \Lambda ^6}{36864 \pi ^4}.
$$
This disagreement clearly indicates something in my procedure is wrong. In fact, if I average the three results and multiply by 2, I find a more sensible answer
$$
\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{5 i g^2 \Lambda ^6}{36864 \pi ^4}+2\frac{11 i g^2 \Lambda ^6}{36864 \pi ^4}\right) = \frac{ i g^2 \Lambda ^6}{2048 \pi ^4}.
$$
Although I don't understand what exactly is going on, supposing I do need to average over the various momentum assignments, the factor of two I obtain in the numerator makes sense since there is no longer a symmetry when permuting the momentum labels of the two $a$-lines.

If someone can explain in detail what is going on here, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to impose that all momenta running in the loop are cut off at $\Lambda$. In particular, the correct integral can be written down by starting with the manifestly symmetric expression
$$
D = \frac{1}{4}\int^\Lambda \frac{d^4 p d^4 k d^4 q}{(2\pi)^{12}}(2\pi)^4\delta^{(4)}(p + k + q) \frac{i}{p^2}\frac{i}{q^2}\frac{i}{r^2}(-i g p\cdot k)^2.
$$
Integrating over the $\delta$-function yields
$$
D = \frac{i^2}{4}\int^\Lambda \frac{2\pi^2 p^3 dp 4\pi k^3\sin\theta dk d\theta}{(2\pi)^{12}}(2\pi)^4 \frac{i}{-p^2}\frac{i}{-q^2}\frac{i\Theta(\Lambda - (p^2 + k^2 + 2 p k \cos\theta))}{p^2 + k^2 + 2 p k \cos\theta}(i g pk\cos\theta)^2.
$$
The result is
$$
D = \frac{i g^2\Lambda^6}{2048\pi^4}.
$$